# Is there a possibility to change the position of the textView if the text goes out of the screen frame?

Tags: android, xml, kotlin

The situation is: I have a constraint layout with 3 TextViews in a row

```
        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:id="@+id/constraint"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/small"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:text="5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/medium"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Some text, not too long"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/small"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/big"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Text, that can be extremely long, but can be also short"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/medium"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

The last textView can be very long and when it is, I would like to move this textView under textView with id medium, so that the text in the text view is not separated. That means, I do not want to display text within a textView on two lines, I want to have text displayed in one line. If the text is short: on the same level as other textViews(picture 1), if the text is too big to fit the screen, the whole textView should be displayed under the second textView(@+id/medium) - picture 2.

Is it in general possible to do so? If yes, I would appreciate it, if you give me some hints.
With what I tried to do I can only move the rest of the text to a new line and display the textView in two lines, but that is not what I really want to see.

Standard situation, when text is not too big:

[image: Standard situation, when text is not too big]

What I would like to have if the text is too big:

[image: What I would like to have if the text is too big]

Comment: @DavidKroukamp unfortunatelly not. The solution here breaks the text into two lines and that is what I'm trying to avoid. I need the whole textView(the last one) to display under the second textView (and only in the situation of a long text)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Flow` (no not that one) which is a flexbox-style layout helper for `ConstraintLayout`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/constraint"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.helper.widget.Flow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:constraint_referenced_ids="small, medium, big"
        app:flow_horizontalBias="0"
        app:flow_horizontalGap="10dp"
        app:flow_horizontalStyle="packed"
        app:flow_wrapMode="chain"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/small"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:text="5" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/medium"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Some text, not too long" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/big"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Text, that can be extremely long, but can be also short" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

It basically just lets you define a chain of elements and handles their constraints (note the `tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"` in the main layout, you don't put them on the views themselves) and then you can set it to wrap when things go off the screen, etc. There are a bunch of tweaks you can do, like setting a max number of elements on a line, forming an aligned grid, etc

There's a pretty good visual guide here:
https://proandroiddev.com/awesomeness-of-constraintlayout-flow-aa0b5edd5df

Comment: Thanks a lot! It seems to be working good for me, it really pushes the whole textView to the next line. I'm going to play around with the code a little more to get to know Flow, but that is obviously what I wanted. And the link is very helpful!